# Discrete maths proposition, proof for multiplication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have this multiplication table for ℤ5,

```
  *   [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
------------------------------- 
 [0]  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
 [1]  [0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
 [2]  [0] [2] [4] [1] [3]
 [3]  [0] [3] [1] [4] [2]
 [4]  [0] [4] [3] [2] [1]
```

How do i get the identity for multiplication and the multiplicative inverses for all the elements? i know that the identity is [1]. am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are. So the multiplicative inverse of $[2]$, say, is whatever $[k]$ satisfies $[2][k]=[1]=[k][2]$; what $[k]$ is that?

Comment: so are you implying that whatever gives a result of = [1] is the inverse?

Comment: Once you know that $[1]$ is the multiplicative identity, that’s the definition of multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Did you find an inverse of $[0]$ by the way?

Answer (score 1):

The identity may be determined by trying to find a column in which each entry is identical to the element representing the corresponding row.
Equivalently, you may also look for a row having a similar property.

Once you have the identity, you can use Brian's method to figure out the inverse for each element.